# QuickBooks Web Connector: "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream" but qb*XML Validator says xml is valid

Tags: python-2.7, qbxml

QuickBooks Web Connector is sending the `QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.` message to my receiveResponseXML method even though my xml checks out in the qb*XML Validator. I have included the authenticate and sendRequestXML methods from my QBTalker class below (other required methods are also in the class; QB Web Connector talks to clientVersion, authenticate, sendRequestXML in that order before sending the hresult value `0x80040400` and the message value `QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.` to receiveResponseXML):

```
class QBTalker(ServiceBase):
    qbxml_version = ''
    request_seq_no = 0
    ticket_id = ''
    @srpc(String, String, _returns=Iterable(String))
    def authenticate(user, pswd):
        #ticket_id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(50))
        QBTalker.ticket_id = 'COMPANY NAME IN QUICKBOOKS'
        for each in [QBTalker.ticket_id, '', '', '']:
            yield each
    @srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=String)
    def sendRequestXML(id, strHCPResponse, strCompanyFileName, qbXMLCountry, qbXMLMajorVers, qbXMLMinorVers):
        '''if id != QBTalker.ticket_id:
            return -1
        else:
'''
        qbxml_version = str(qbXMLMajorVers) + '.' + str(qbXMLMinorVers)
        QBTalker.request_seq_no += 1
        xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerQueryRq requestID="2">
            <FullName>COMPANY NAME IN QUICKBOOKS</FullName>
        </CustomerQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
'''
        QBTalker.request_seq_no = 99
        root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
        return lxml.etree.tostring(root)
    @srpc(String, String, String, String, _returns=Integer8)
    def receiveResponseXML(ticket, response, hresult, message):
        response = response
        hresult = hresult
        message = message
        return 100
    @srpc(String, String, String, _returns=String)
    def connectionError(ticket, hresult, message):
        print("QuickBooks Web Connector says a connection error has occurred.")
        print("hresult is " + hresult)
        print("message is " + message)
    @srpc(String, _returns=String)
    def getLastError(ticket):
        print("QuickBooks Web Connector is asking for the last error on ticket id " + ticket if ticket else "None")
        return ticket
    @srpc(String, _returns=String)
    def closeConnection(ticket):
        print("QuickBooks Web Connector is closing the connection for ticket id " + ticket if ticket else "None")
        return ticket
if __name__=='__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app = Application([QBTalker], tns='http://developer.intuit.com/',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
        out_protocol=Soap11(encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True),
    )
wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(app)
server = make_server('localhost', 7789, wsgi_app)
server.serve_forever()
```

UPDATE:
Ok, I got the "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream" error to go away by adding the following import statement

```
from spyne.model.primitive import AnyXml
```

and changing the decorator line above my def sendRequestXML line from

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=String)
```

to

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=AnyXml)
```

I think this may change the mime type from text/html to text/xml, but I am not sure. I also changed

```
def authenticate(user, pswd):
```

to

```
def authenticate(strUserName, strPassword):
```

and

```
def sendRequestXML(id, strHCPResponse, strCompanyFileName, qbXMLCountry, qbXMLMajorVers, qbXMLMinorVers):
```

to

```
def sendRequestXML(ticket, strHCPResponse, strCompanyFileName, qbXMLCountry, qbXMLMajorVers, qbXMLMinorVers):
```

as I now understand the names of the function arguments are specific.

However, I am still getting nothing returned from my query. Can anyone point out what I should change? I am using the same value as would be entered for the NAME field in a !CUST iif file for the COMPANY NAME IN QUICKBOOKS in my code above. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although changing

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=String)
```

to

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=AnyXml)
```

fixed the xml error I was getting, I was still not receiving any feedback to my query. Since then I installed RawCap.exe and looked at the communication between my web service and the QuickBooks Web Connector and compared it to the communication between the QuickBooks Php DevKit and the Web Connector when it creates a customer. I noticed my web service was stripping the `<?qbxml version="13.0" ?>` tag out of the packets. So I changed

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=AnyXml)
```

back to

```
@srpc(String, String, String, String, UnsignedInteger, UnsignedInteger, _returns=Unicode)
```

and I changed

```
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
return lxml.etree.tostring(root)
```

to

```
#root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
#return lxml.etree.tostring(root)
return xml
```

and

```
app = Application([QBTalker], tns='http://developer.intuit.com/',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'),
        out_protocol=Soap11(),
    )
```

to

```
app = Application([QBTalker], tns='http://developer.intuit.com/',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'),
        out_protocol=Soap11(encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True),
    )
```

and it started working. The keys seem to have been removing lxml.etree parsing and changing the return type in the decorator function from AnyXml (to either String or Unicode), although the reason I originally changed to using lxml.etree parsing was because I was getting the original error when returning unicode ...